# How can I use Qt to encrypt/decrypte/play a video?

Tags: qt

I am looking for a way to encrypt an video file and then use decrypt it to ram and play it directly.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are trying to read the video's data into a `QUrl` which results in an invalid `QUrl` which `player` (you haven't stated what that is) obviously can't open.  As `QMediaPlayer` can play videos directly from a `QUrl`, perhaps you should state _why_ you need the ability to play from `QDataStream`?

Comment: My apology.@cmannett85 Can you please read my answer and help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setMedia takes a QIOdevice as second argument:

```
  #include <QMediaPlayer>
  #include <QApplication>
  #include <QFile>
  int main(int argc, char ** argv)
  {
      QApplication app(argc,argv);
      QString fileName = app.arguments().at(1);

      QFile io(fileName);
      io.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

      QMediaPlayer player;

      player.setMedia(QUrl("test.mp3"), &io);
      player.play();

      return app.exec();
  }
```

but just in case you **really** mean QDataStream:

QDataStream is buffered io, QIODevice is direct io, they're not compatible, so you have to double buffer like this:

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QDataStream>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QString fileName = app.arguments().at(1);

    // our double buffer
    QByteArray bufferSpace;

    // our stream on which we can put "media" data
    QDataStream stream(&bufferSpace, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    // this is just demo data
    QFile io(fileName);
    io.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    stream << io.readAll();

    // open an IO Device on our buffer
    QBuffer buffer(&bufferSpace);
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);

    // give the IO to the media player
    QMediaPlayer player;
    player.setMedia(QUrl("test.mp3"), &buffer);
    player.play();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**edit**

here's a faster version of that "crypto" code you posted without using a buffer for the entire file:

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QDataStream>

static const unsigned char key = 0xAB;
class MyFunnyCrypto : public QFile /*or subclass any other IO*/
{
protected:
    virtual qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxSize)
    {
        qint64 r = QFile::readData(data, maxSize);
        if (r > 0) {
            for (qint64 i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                data[i] = data[i]^key;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

};


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QString fileName = app.arguments().at(1);


    MyFunnyCrypto io;
    io.setFileName(fileName);
    io.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    // give the IO to the media player
    QMediaPlayer player;
    player.setMedia(QUrl("test.mp3"), &io);
    player.play();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Can you please read my answer below and help me?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @aep .
It doesn't have anything to do with QDataStream, and it's quite simple.
Encryption:

```
unsigned char key = 0xAB;
QFile file("test.mp3");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray byteArray = file.readAll();
for(int i=1024;i<byteArray.length();i++){
    byteArray[i] = byteArray[i]^key;
}
file.close();

QFile encrypted("encrypted.mp3");
encrypted.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
encrypted.write(byteArray);
encrypted.close();
```

And decryption:

```
unsigned char key = 0xAB;
QFile file("encrypted.mp3");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
auto byteArray = file.readAll();
for(int i=1024;i<byteArray.length();i++){
     byteArray[i] = byteArray[i]^key;
}

QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);

// give the IO to the media player
QMediaPlayer player;
player.setMedia(QUrl(), &buffer);
player.play();
```

In the for-loop, I want to declare i as `qint64` rather than `int`. But the compiler shows `QByteArray::​operator[](int i)`.

Comment: int seems correct, since the intermediate buffer can only hold INT_MAX elements anyway. why would you want qint64 here?

Comment: I want to manipulate a file whose size is about 200m. Oh， `int` should work fine too. @aep

Comment: It's really not OK for you to ask a (confused) question about one thing, wait for responses, then reveal that you meant something entirely different, and then answer your own question. Please edit your question for what you are _really asking_ so other people can find the information.