# Decrypting a video for QMediaplayer without creating a buffer for the entire file

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement a custom encryption/decryption algorithm for encrypted video playback in Qt. It would be quite easy to decrypt the whole file and then pass that to the QMediaPlayer, but I am trying to avoid that because these video files are several gigs in size.

To keep everything simple, I've made a very dumbed down diagram of what I am trying to achieve. The example shown is not the actual encryption/decryption algorithm.

[image]

An encrypted video file is broken down into 32-Byte chunks, which are numbered with n. Every chunk is then XOR'd with a SHA256 hash of n. The result should then be passed to the QMediaPlayer.

I did some research, but I am relatively new to Qt. Here's a link to a solution for a similar problem:
[How can I use Qt to encrypt/decrypte/play a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316886/how-can-i-use-qt-to-encrypt-decrypte-play-a-video)

This solution creates a buffer to decrypt a video on the fly, but only works by calculating it on a byte-by-byte basis.

**Edit:**

The solution in the link uses a 1-byte buffer.

I would like to process 32-byte chunks, while being able to track which chunk I am busy processing.

Suppose I would like to stream a 20kB video. That would mean that it gets divided into 640 chunks that need to be processed individually, while being able to keep track of which chunk I am currently decrypting.

How would I go about creating a buffer that is 32-Bytes long and that is able to keep track of which part of the file I'm processing?

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for the edit. :)

Comment: Instead of inventing your own algorithm, I would recommend using some existing block cipher, for example AES in CBC mode.

Comment: True, though in this case I'm required to use my own algorithm.

Comment: You could decrypt several bytes at a time and feed those. What question is left open from your link? Can you be specific please?